Angle in a triangle
The angle of triangle ABC also belongs to triangle AHC. The problem states that $\tan (\angle A) = 5$ $\frac{CH}{AH} = 5$ or $\frac{BC}{AC} = 5$ or both.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not only should you edit the question for clarity, but to help you best, you should tell us 1) what it means to you that $\tan{A}=5$, and 2) what it means to you when you draw an altitude to the right angle within a right triangle.

Both $\triangle ACH$ and $\triangle ABC$ are right triangle with base angle $\angle A$. And $\tan = \frac {\sin}{\cos}$ so... there really shouldn't be any confusion.

The rule for tangent is $\tan={\frac{opposite}{adjacent}}$,
So, the opposite side of $∠$ in triangle ABC is BC, and the adjacent side of $∠$ is AB, so for triangle ABC, it is $\frac{BC}{AB}$
For triangle AHC, the opposite side of $∠$ is CH and the adjacent side of $∠$ is AH, therefore the answer is $\frac{CH}{AH}$
So, the answer is  $\frac{BC}{AB}$ for triangle ABC, and for triangle AHC, it's $\frac{CH}{AH}$.
Hope this answers your question!
